# Toggle between admin / user view in React

Tags: reactjs, toggle, setstate

I know there are alot of questions similar to this, but Im not able to find a solution and been stuck for awhile know. So would love if someone could help me out.
Im trying to get my app to toggle between Admin and User view. I get to app to start with the Adminview and it goes over to Userview when user button is pressed. But then Im not able to get back to admin view when pressing the admin button.

If anyone have some extra time to explain to me, what Im missing I would really appreciate it.

My Code:

```
import React from "react";
import AdminView from "./components/adminView";
import UserView from "./components/userView";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeUser = this.changeUser.bind(this); 
      adminView: true,
  }

  changeUser(isAdmin) {
    this.setState({adminView : isAdmin => { 
     this.adminView = !this.adminView
    } 
  });
  };

  render() { 
    if (this.state.adminView === true) {
    return (
      <div className="container text-center">
      <div className="btn-group">
        <button onClick={() => this.changeUser(true)}>ADMIN</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.changeUser(false)}>USER</button>
      </div>
        <AdminView addProject={newProject => this.addProject(newProject)} />
      </div>
    );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="container text-center">
        <div className="btn-group">
        <button onClick={() => this.changeUser(true)}>ADMIN</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.changeUser(false)}>USER</button>
      </div>
          <UserView />
        </div>
      )
     }
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: are you sure that the `adminView` is a state? he code shows it is only a variable not a state

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep my example to point and with small changes as possible. You can find the revised version of the code here:

`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeUser = this.changeUser.bind(this);

    // this part was missing
    this.state = {
      adminView: true,
    }
  }

  changeUser(isAdmin) {
    // you should alter state properties, in previous version you were assingning a function to adminView not passing a function to setState function
    this.setState(({adminView}) => ({
      adminView: !adminView,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.adminView === true) {
    return (
      <div className="container text-center">
      <div className="btn-group">
        { /* since you are not really using isAdmin variable you can remove it ? */ }
        <button onClick={this.changeUser}>ADMIN</button>
        <button onClick={this.changeUser}>USER</button>
      </div>
        Admin View
      </div>
    );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="container text-center">
        <div className="btn-group">
        <button onClick={this.changeUser}>ADMIN</button>
        <button onClick={this.changeUser}>USER</button>
      </div>
          User View
        </div>
      )
     }
  }
}

console.log('here', document.getElementById('app'))
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

`
https://codepen.io/yerguden/pen/JjjwwQV

I listed the changes below but you should directly check codepen first as I tried to comment on the errors and they should be easier to grasp.

First thing is you didn't assign an initial state, I think adminView: true, should produce an error when you try to run.

Second mistake using setState incorrectly in your example you are setting the value of adminView to a function and I don't think that was the aim of the code.

The last change on the codepen is more of a cleanup, I removed true/false parameters from callback since the function is designed to work as toggle (if I got the code correctly).

Note as a new contributor: I am new here :) and I am not sure if other fixes/changes to the your code should be a part of this answer. But let me know if you need some more help and I will try to edit my changes.